# Unable to uninstall virtualbox network drivers

Tags: networking, windows-vista, drivers, virtualbox

Last time I tried to uninstall virtualbox, it failed with a BSOD. Since then, I am unable to install any version of virtualbox. The uninstaller seem's to fail to. When i look in my network drivers list, the virtualbox driver's are still there ('VirtualBox Bridged Networking Driver Miniport'). I can do what ever I want, there is no way to uninstall them. I think there might be some registery that where not removed or something like that but I don't know how to remove them safely or what registery I should remove.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: This question is confusing. From the way it is written, it would seem you have the VirtualBox virtual network driver installed in the physical (host) PC! If so, I would love to know how you did that.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The registry keys for Oracle VirtualBox are located there:

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\services\VBoxDrv
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\services\VBoxNetAdp
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\services\VBoxNetFlt
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\services\VBoxUSBMon
```

Corresponding files in the file system:

- VBoxDrv  VirtualBox Support Drive:
  c:\windows\system32\drivers\vboxdrv.sys
- VBoxNetAdpVirtualBox Host-Only Network Adapter Driver"
  c:\windows\system32\drivers\vboxnetadp.sys
- VBoxNetFltVirtualBox Bridged Networking Driver:
  c:\windows\system32\drivers\vboxnetflt.sys
- VBoxUSBMonVirtualBox USB Monitor Driver:
  c:\windows\system32\drivers\vboxusbmon.sys

**Suggested tool** to finds these keys. disable, delete or access them in the file system or the registry:

[MS TechNet Sysinternals **Autoruns**](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb963902)

Comment: The problem is the auto runs. If you run the tool above, filter for VBox, remove the auto-running services, and reboot - you can then uninstall virtualbox using the default installer no problem.

Answer (score 7):

Just go to your **Device Manager**, expand the *network adapters*, right click virtualbox related network adapters and uninstall them!

Comment: This is the right answer, the right way to do it, and obvious once you think about it :) - you can also select delete to drivers when you choose to 'uninstall' the device.

Comment: I get BSOD just like uninstalling VirtualBox when uninstalling the drivers

Answer (score 4):

Okay, this was really really a hard one. I've tried a felt 100 things.

My solution (Windows 8) was

1. Uninstall VirtualBox and reboot
2. Download [RunAsSystem](http://www.raymond.cc/blog/full-control-permission-to-delete-or-edit-restricted-windows-registry/) and start "C:\Windows\regedit.exe" with it (You can check with TaskManager that it really runs as "System")
3. Remove "[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\ControlSet001\Enum\Root\SUN_VBOXNETFLTMP](http://eqagunn.blogspot.de/2011/01/multiple-unknown-devices-in-device.html)"
4. Remove the keys recommended by @climenole
5. Go to HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\ControlSet001\Enum\ROOT\NET and delete all "VirtualBo Host-Only ..." adapters.
6. Reboot
7. Use something like CCleaner to clean the registry
8. Reinstall VirtualBox

Comment: sounds good, but for me, in Win8.1, RunAsSystem adds the context menu option (after crashing), but it fails to run RegEdit (or any other program)

Comment: I successfully used http://live.sysinternals.com/psexec.exe with the -s and -i options to run regedit as SYSTEM

Answer (score 1):

Download the version that you want to uninstall and execute it.

https://www.virtualbox.org/wiki/Download_Old_Builds

The installer will give you the option for Repair or Remove the Virtualbox version installed.

After the remove you will must reboot your computer.

Comment: Tried, still got a Bsod

Answer (score -1):

A System Restore to the date before the installation should sort it.

Failing that, export:

HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\DIFxApp\Components

Open the .reg file in notepad and substitute the HKEY_CURRENT_USER with HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE

Import the .reg file and reboot.

Comment: I am very curious to know what it will do exactly?